# multiple belongs_to on model causing errors with accepts_nested_attributes_for on parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, simple-form

I've got a child model which `belongs_to` two potential parent models. One of which I am trying to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `simple_form`. Doing this gives me this error:
`You tried to define an association named transaction on the model Exchange, but this will conflict with a method transaction already defined by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.`

Here is my code:

Exchange model

```
class Exchange < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :transaction
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :transaction
end
```

Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
  monetize :budgeted_cents
end
```

Transaction model

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'Category', :primary_key => 'category_id'
  belongs_to :exchange, :class_name => 'Exchange', :primary_key => 'exchange_id'
  validates :note, presence: true
  monetize :amount_cents, with_model_currency: :in_cents_currency

  def self.all_currencies(hash)
    hash.keys
  end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong here or am I approaching the problem from the wrong angle?

Thanks

Comment: As the message says, you need to change the name of the association to something other than `transaction`.

Comment: But isn't the name of the association (`transaction`) referring to the name of the model it's making the association _to_? (i.e. it has to be named `transaction`) @vee

Comment: Yes, but as `transaction` is a method already defined in ActiveRecord it is kind of a reserved word.  You could do `has_one :tx, class_name: 'Transaction'` then `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tx` in your `Exchange` model.

Comment: More on AR `transaction` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-transaction.

Comment: I made that change, but now in my controller I am getting an error `can't write unknown attribute 'exchange_id'` when I do something like `@exchange.tx = Transaction.new`. Is this also related to `transaction` being kind of reserved? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: What version of Rails are you on?

Comment: 4.2.0 (15 chars) @vee

Comment: nevermind, all good (had my schema slightly wrong). Want to make this into an answer so I can accept it @vee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vee pointed out, 'transaction' is a reserved-word, though this was never enforced until a Rails 4.1.x version.

Changing the term 'transaction' app-wide would require work well outside a client's budget. So the solution I used, was to replace the module "ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder" with a duplicate of what is here (adjust for your Rails version):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb

I placed a copy of that association.rb code at the same location in the hierarchy within my app (lib/active_record/associations/builder), except with the following lines commented-out:

```
# if model.dangerous_attribute_method?(name)
# raise ArgumentError, "You tried to define an association named #{name} on the model #{model.name}, but " \
# "this will conflict with a method #{name} already defined by Active Record. " \
# "Please choose a different association name."
# end
```

You could try only skipping this (modifying the 'if') only when 'name' matches the conflicting term 'transaction'. 
For any others out there who are stuck, this route prevents having to remain at Rails Version 4.0.x or an early 4.1 beta.

Comment: I had to down vote this as this kind of hackery should not be encouraged. This is not a solution to the problem, this is paving the way for mysterious bugs. The proper solution is to search-and-replace the association and rename it to something else, e.g. `belongs_to :my_transaction, class_name: 'Transaction'`.

Comment: I'll have my client send you the bill :) - it is referenced throughout the entire app-code (before I inherited the project).  Code that works should not be broken within a major version.  At the very least, a gem could be provided by the 'breakers' to restore previous working functionality.  As well, this code-fix merely comments out new source which is the cause of the breakage.